# How to display a result outside of a PHP FOR loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I try to show the result outside the loop, but only one item appears.
How can I do it?

```
$content = $_POST;
for($i=1; $i < $content['itemCount'] + 1; $i++) {
    $name = 'item_name_'.$i;
    $quantity =  'item_quantity_'.$i;
    $price = 'item_price_'.$i;
    $body .= 'item #'.$i.': ';
    $body .= $content[$name].' '.$content[$quantity].' '.$content[$price];
    $body .= '<br>';
}
//outside of loop
echo $content[$quantity]. ' ' . $content[$name];
```

Comment: I believe what you are wanting to echo outside the loop is the `$body` variable which you have been concatenating content to. Echoing out the $content variable will not result in the outcome you desire.

Comment: For loop is running every time and is overwriting older values with newer ones and finally when you are printing it outside for loop only last stored value is displayed

Comment: I had made a mistake, I could solve it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `$quantity` variable is set with the last value of the loop, if you want to display all of the values you need to echo out the results inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Loops have a local scope, what you wish for is not possible, it is possible however to create and access an outside scope.